# TypeScript - Get object from looking inside getter

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a random user object:

(On TypeScript 3.7.5)

```
{
    moderator: {
        id: '38232'
    }
}
```

If I did `UserDisplay.get(randomUser)` would output `{ userPath: 'modeator.id', userType: 'MODERATOR' }` because it saw inside `randomUser` and saw that `moderator` object was present.

How would I ascertain, using TypeScript, that any random user would be correctly associated with its pertaining `UserType` enumeration.

If I did:

```js
UserDisplay.get({
    moderator: {
        id: '38232'
    }
})
```

It would spit out:

```js
  [UserType.MODERATOR, {
    userPath: 'moderator.id',
    userType: UserType.MODERATOR
  }],
```

Here's what I have so far using the TypeScript playground.

```js
enum UserType {
    USER = "USER",
    MODERATOR = "MODERATOR",
    ADMIN = "ADMIN",
}

interface IUserFormat {
  userPath: string;
  userType: UserType
}

const UserDisplay = new Map<UserType, IUserFormat>([
  [UserType.ADMIN, {
    userPath: 'admin.id',
    userType: UserType.ADMIN
  }],
  [UserType.MODERATOR, {
    userPath: 'moderator.id',
    userType: UserType.MODERATOR
  }],
  [UserType.USER, {
    userPath: 'user.id',
    userType: UserType.USER
  }],
]);

const randomUser = {
    moderator: {
        id: '38232'
    }
};

console.log(UserDisplay.get(randomUser)); // should output { userPath: 'modeator.id', userType: 'MODERATOR' }
```

Comment: should be doable with mapped types!

Comment: I think we can get it TS to know the correct output based on the object properties.  I'm playing with this using string template types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely could create a less-typed version of this, but I saw this as an opportunity to play with the new [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)! This feature allows us to convert string literal types from a lowercase key like `'moderator'` to the uppercase `'MODERATOR'` and also from key `'moderator'` to the path `'moderator.id'`.  With these types we should be able to infer the exact output for `randomUser` just based on its properties.

The biggest trouble that I had was that a plain string like `'MODERATOR'` does not extend the enum type `UserType` because enums are special, but it *does* extend `keyof typeof UserType` which is the union of the keys of the enum.

This interface describes what an output should look like:

```
interface IUserFormat<T extends string> {
  userPath: `${Lowercase<T>}.id`;
  userType: T;
}
```

This function converts a `UserType` to its format object.  We have to assert as `${Lowercase<T>}.id` because any string template is just `string` otherwise.

```
const toFormat = <T extends UserType>(userType: T): IUserFormat<T> => ({
    userPath: `${userType.toLowerCase()}.id` as `${Lowercase<T>}.id`,
    userType: userType,
})
```

Our function looks for the key of the object that matches a `UserType` and calls `toFormat` on it to get the format object.

The "fancy version" of the types can infer that the user type for your `randomUser` object is `IUserFormat<"MODERATOR">`

```
const userDisplay = <K extends string>(
    object: Record<K, { id: string }>
): IUserFormat<Extract<Uppercase<K>, keyof typeof UserType>> => {
    const type = Object.values(UserType).find(type => type.toLowerCase() in object);
    if (!type) {
        throw new Error("no user type found");
    }
    return toFormat(type) as any;
}

const format = userDisplay(randomUser); // type: IUserFormat<"MODERATOR">
```

Unfortunately it does not understand that `"MODERATOR"` is assignable to `UserType`.  So you might just want to return `IUserFormat<UserType>`, which also removes the need for any `as` assertion.

```
const userDisplay = <K extends string>(
    object: Record<K, { id: string }>
): IUserFormat<UserType> => {
    const type = Object.values(UserType).find(type => type.toLowerCase() in object);
    if (!type) {
        throw new Error("no user type found");
    }
    return toFormat(type);
}

const format = userDisplay(randomUser); // type: IUserFormat<UserType>
```

note: I am assuming that the user object will have at least one of the user type properties and I am throwing a run-time error if this is not the case, but I haven't actually enforced it in the types.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NVn77N)

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortuantely, I am on TS 3.7.5 so I cannot use this but I did learn a lot.